# Optimizing a for in loop with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an NSMutableDictionary that contains a MPMediaItem and a string of it's title for it's key. I currently have 1,777 items in the dictionary.

I am looping through the dictionary looking for a fuzzy match with a supplied NSString. How can I speed it up? It takes about 6 seconds every time it's run.

I'll just past in the loop itself

```
@autoreleasepool {
        float currentFoundValue = 1000.0;
        NSMutableArray *test;
        MPMediaItemCollection *collection;
        float match;
        for(id key in artistDictionary)
        {
            NSString *thisArtist = key;
            int suppliedCount = [stringValue length];
            int keyCount = [thisArtist length];
            if(suppliedCount > keyCount)
            {
                match = [StringDistance stringDistance:thisArtist :stringValue];
            } else {
                match = [StringDistance stringDistance:stringValue :thisArtist];
            }
            if(match < currentFoundValue)
            {
                currentFoundValue = match;
                test = [artistDictionary objectForKey:thisArtist];
                collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:test];
            }
        }
```

...

Comment: I have found that objectForKey is a bad culprit here. The stringDistance method is extremely quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `-enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:`, and use the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option.

Comment: Alright - I implemented that and it's shaving about a second off the total time. Is that about all I can do here?

Comment: Use Instruments to see what's using up the time, my guess is that your string distance calculation is what you should care about the most. 1700 elements isn't that much.

Answer (score 0):

You have two performance bootle necks:

1. You potentially recreate the `MPMediaItemCollection` instance once for each iteration, when only the last one created is needed.
2. -[NSDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] is much faster when both the key and value of the enumerated dictionary is needed.

Change into something like this:

```
float currentFoundValue = 1000.0;
NSMutableArray *test = nil;
MPMediaItemCollection *collection;
float match;
[artistDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                                          usingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) 
{
    NSString *thisArtist = key;
    int suppliedCount = [stringValue length];
    int keyCount = [thisArtist length];
    if(suppliedCount > keyCount)
    {
        match = [StringDistance stringDistance:thisArtist :stringValue];
    } else {
        match = [StringDistance stringDistance:stringValue :thisArtist];
    }
    if(match < currentFoundValue)
    {
        currentFoundValue = match;
        test = obj;
    }
}];
collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:test];
```

Comment: I implemented enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock and it's saving me maybe 500ms. One thing to note, those variables require a __block assignment for access within the block. I have implemented hashKeys and other things to get a search down to about 750ms total